# el codigo puesto en la funcion Else se activa sin llamar la funcion en PYTHON 3.8.1 AYUDA

Tags: python, python-3.x

Se activa lo que hay en la función `else` sin llamarlo hasta con llamando la función `if` bien

Estoy haciendo un piedra papel o tijera con un `randomizer` para escoger entre piedra papel o tijera

Mi código en PYTHON 3.8.1 :

```
#programado al 100% solo por ticua
#
#gracias a la libreria random por el uso de randomrange
#

from random import randrange


print("1. piedra")
print("2. papel")
print("3. tijera")
opc = input("elige una opcion (1/2/3) : ")


key = randrange(0, 99)

"""
#################### PIEDRA ############################

if key < 33:
    print("piedra")

if key == 33:
    print("piedra")


######################## PAPEL #########################


if key > 33 and key < 66:
    print("papel")




####################### TIJERA #############################

if key > 66:
    print("tijera")

if key == 66:
    print("tijera")



#################### IF PIEDRA #############################3
"""

if opc == "1" and key < 33:
    print("piedra vs piedra = EMPATE")

if opc == "1" and key == 33:
     print("piedra vs piedra = EMPATE")


if opc == "1" and key > 33 and key < 66:
    print("piedra vs papel = GANA PAPEL --- PERDISTE")

if opc == "1" and key == 66:
     print("piedra vs tijera = GANA PIEDRA --- GANASTE")


if opc == "1" and key > 66:
    print("piedra vs tijera = GANA PIEDRA --- GANASTE")


#################### IF PAPEL #############################3


if opc == "2" and key < 33:
    print("papel vs piedra = GANA PAPEL --- GANASTE")

if opc == "2" and key == 33:
    print("papel vs piedra = GANA PAPEL --- GANASTE")


if opc == "2" and key > 33 and key < 66:
    print("papel vs papel = EMPATE")

if opc == "2" and key == 66:
    print("papel vs tijera = GANA TIJERA --- PERDISTE")


if opc == "2" and key > 66:
    print("papel vs tijera = GANA PIEDRA --- PERDISTE")


#################### IF TIJERA #############################


if opc == "3" and key < 33:
       print("tijera vs piedra = GANA PIEDRA --- PERDISTE")

if opc == "3" and key == 33:
       print("piedra vs piedra = GANA PIEDRA --- PERDISTE")


if opc == "3" and key > 33 and key < 66:
    print("tijera vs papel = GANA TIJERA --- GANASTE")

if opc == "3" and key == 66:
     print("tijera vs tijera = EMPATE")


if opc == "3" and key > 66:
   print("tijera vs tijera = EMPATE")

else:
    print(opc,"no es una opcion")
```

Y lo que me da escogiendo entre 1(que es piedra), 2(que es papel) o 3(que es tijera)

Y que no es una opción cuando ejecuta el código de la función `if` llamada

Salida del código

```
1. piedra (esto es un print)
2. papel (esto es un print)
3. tijera (esto es un print)
elige una opcion (1/2/3) : 2 (el 2 es un input)
papel vs piedra = GANA PAPEL --- GANASTE (calculo random de la randomizer)
2 no es una opcion (el else que dice que no es una opcion siendo una opcion)
```

Se que arreglar errores en python es fácil pero por alguna razón este es un caso particular donde no funciona y no se como arreglarlo.

Comment: alguno sabe como arreglarlo

Comment: alguno sabe como se arregla??

Comment: Por favor no le coloques solucionado al título de tu pregunta, en su lugar te invito a marcar la respuesta que dio la solución como aceptada

Answer (score 1):

El último `else`, solo no entrará siempre y cuando `opc` sea `"3"` y `key` se mayor a `66`, ya que el `else` pertenece al último `if`:

```py
if opc == "3" and key > 66:
   print("tijera vs tijera = EMPATE") 

else:
    # solo cuando sea un empate de tijera vs tijera NO entrará AQUÍ
    print(opc,"no es una opción")
```

Por lo anterior, lo que se debería hacer es crear un `if`, que englobe a todos los demás, y que compruebe si es que el `input` corresponde a 1, 2 o 3 y de no ser así salte al `else`:

```py
from random import randrange

print("1. piedra")
print("2. papel")
print("3. tijera")
opc = input("elige una opcion (1/2/3) : ")


key = randrange(0, 99)

if opc == "1" or  opc == "2" or opc == "3" : #El único if que tiene else

    if opc == "1" and key < 33:
        print("piedra vs piedra = EMPATE")

    if opc == "1" and key == 33:
        print("piedra vs piedra = EMPATE")


    if opc == "1" and key > 33 and key < 66:
        print("piedra vs papel = GANA PAPEL --- PERDISTE")

    if opc == "1" and key == 66:
        print("piedra vs tijera = GANA PIEDRA --- GANASTE")


    if opc == "1" and key > 66:
        print("piedra vs tijera = GANA PIEDRA --- GANASTE")


    #################### IF PAPEL #############################3


    if opc == "2" and key < 33:
        print("papel vs piedra = GANA PAPEL --- GANASTE")

    if opc == "2" and key == 33:
        print("papel vs piedra = GANA PAPEL --- GANASTE")


    if opc == "2" and key > 33 and key < 66:
        print("papel vs papel = EMPATE")

    if opc == "2" and key == 66:
        print("papel vs tijera = GANA TIJERA --- PERDISTE")


    if opc == "2" and key > 66:
        print("papel vs tijera = GANA PIEDRA --- PERDISTE")


    #################### IF TIJERA #############################


    if opc == "3" and key < 33:
        print("tijera vs piedra = GANA PIEDRA --- PERDISTE")

    if opc == "3" and key == 33:
        print("piedra vs piedra = GANA PIEDRA --- PERDISTE")


    if opc == "3" and key > 33 and key < 66:
        print("tijera vs papel = GANA TIJERA --- GANASTE")

    if opc == "3" and key == 66:
        print("tijera vs tijera = EMPATE")


    if opc == "3" and key > 66:
        print("tijera vs tijera = EMPATE")

else: #Pertenece al if de arriba
    print(opc,"no es una opcion")
```

> **RESULTADO**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Programe el mismo juego pero mejorado, echale un vistaso:

```
import random
import time
import os

options = {
    # Option > Option
    'piedra': 'tijera',
    'papel': 'piedra',
    'tijera': 'papel',
}

banner = """
[i] Para salir del programa CONTROL-C

[ Piedra, Papel o Tijera!! ]

# Opciones:

|-piedra
|-papel
|-tijera
"""

while True:
    os.system('cls')

    print(banner)

    option_user = input('> Elige una opcion: ')

    if option_user.lower() not in options:
        print('\n> Opcion no valida intenta de nuevo...')
        time.sleep(5)
        continue

    option_random = random.choice(['piedra', 'papel', 'tijera'])

    if option_random == option_user:
        print(f'\n> { option_random } vs { option_user } | EMPATE')
        time.sleep(5)
        continue

    if options[option_random] == option_user:
        print(f'\n> { option_random } vs { option_user } | PERDISTE')
        time.sleep(5)
        continue
    else:
        print(f'\n> { option_random } vs { option_user } | GANASTE')
        time.sleep(5)
        continue
```

Una solucion mas legible, espero haberte ayudado de alguna manera.